# Outlook - Where is the "You have Replied to this Message" info stored

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an issue where I had Outgoing mail in my Outbox, and something then caused Outlook to crash. (Outlook 2013)
All of those mails disappeared.

I can't remember which e-mails I replied to, to redraft.
Most of them were replies on mails.  If I go back to the one of the original Mails, which I replied on, it shows "You have replied .." with a date/time stamp, on the header.

I want to sort all my mail by fields date  so I can see what mail I replied on last night and this morning, prior to the crash

Does anybody know where this is stored?

Comment: "I had Outgoing mail in my Outbox" - if your Outlook has crashed that time, than probably those mails are not sent. Also crash probably didn't deleted your sent mails, so just have a look on the newest items in your sent folder, and everything not present there was lost.

Answer (score 1):

This date is stored in `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME` MAPI property (DASL [http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839918.aspx)). In order to sort by this property, you'll need to create a custom field in your Outlook folder, then write a VBA script that will copy `PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTION_TIME` to this custom field. After that you'll be able to sort by this custom field.

Comment: Hi @thims, do you know of a VBA template for synchronizing a MAPI property to a column/field name?